# Why didn't they open more than one Door of Department of Mystery at once?

Tags: harry-potter

There were total of six people in the circular room. Then why open a single door and use the *Flagrate* charm as compared to opening six doors at once (or five) and have Harry take a look at the open rooms. The room won't spin unless all the doors are shut. They could have also easily kept open one door and looked in others. Why give the room a chance to spin?

Comment: Film or book? .

Comment: I do not remember the film (watched one a long time ago), But this was in the book.

Comment: Because they didn't think of it.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I was thinking if there was any canon reason that only one room can be opened at a time or any other reason they didn't do that.

Answer (score 3):

**Quite simply, because the doors closed automatically once people exited.**

> They crept out of the office and back toward the door into the black
> hallway, which now seemed completely deserted.
>
> They walked a few steps forward, Neville tottering slightly due to
> Hermione’s weight. The door of the Time Room swung shut behind them,
> and the walls began to rotate once more.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

No mention is made of Harry closing the door (and Neville was probably unable to), so this passage would seem to indicate that the doors will swing shut by themselves. Of course, earlier they are described as closing doors, but they were probably holding them open to begin with.

Most likely any simple attempt to hold the door open would fail, since the rotating room was an intentional security feature. Even the lines from *Flagrate* seemed to fade over time, which may have been another security feature:

> With a sinking heart Harry saw that Hermione’s fiery crosses had faded
> from the doors.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

They could not simply have several people hold the doors open and peer into the rooms, since many of the rooms had their own adjoining rooms, which would need to be investigated. And having some people hold the doors open while others explored the rooms would have been a very dangerous idea, since it would have split the group, and left the explorers vulnerable to ambush. They were trying to stay together. All in all, the *Flagrate* spell was the best option.

Comment: Meh, this is a bad problem - you could have one person keep one door open, and check all the others. Also there is mention of closing the doors - Harry asks someone to close the door, and Hermione _flagrates_ one before Luna closes it (both mentioned)

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing they had a feeling that if they tried to keep one door open and open others at the same time, the room would close the doors or blow up or something to make sure it can still spin.

Or it just could be that they never thought of it at the time. They were in a hurry to "save" Sirius, so Harry (or anyone else) never stopped to think about what they could do. After Hermione thought of using the Flaggrate Charm, they pounced on that idea and used it.